# How to simplify this inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

I have the following inequality where $i$, $N$ and $p$ are constants, $j$ is a variable and $p_j$ is the chance that 'event' $j$ is happening:

$$i\geq -pi+((1-p)\cdot \sum ^N _{j=0}(j\cdot p_j))+\sum ^N _{j=i}((1-p)\cdot p_{j-i}\cdot j)$$
How can you simplify this? Preferably it should result in something that has a monotone increasing or decreasing term.

Comment: Is $p$ related to the $p_j$:s? Is $p < 1$?

Comment: And monotone increasing with respect to which variable? I mean, $j$ is a summation index, and not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just do some simplifications for you. (I didn't care about the terms outside of the sums.)

\begin{align}
 \left((1-p)\sum^N _{j=0}j\cdot p_j\right)+\left(\sum ^N _{j=i}(1-p)\cdot p_{j-i}\cdot j \right)& = 
 (1-p)\left(\sum^N _{j=0}j\,p_j+\sum ^N _{j=i}j\,p_{j-i}\right)\\
 & =  (1-p)\left(\sum^N _{j=0}j\,p_j+\sum ^{N-i} _{j=0}(j+i)\,p_j\right)\\
 & =  (1-p)\left(\sum^{N-i} _{j=0}(2j+i)\,p_j+\sum ^{N} _{j=N-i+1}j\,p_j\right).
\end{align}